# Brew formulae install options

Tags: homebrew

I'm trying to write formulae for Brew that would allow the user to opt-in/opt-out of certain functionality of the tool that is being installed. I can't find any documentation whether that is possible.

More specifically I would like to give the developer option to opt-out of crash reports and then formulae could decide which source to use or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Formula Cookbook ¶ Adding optional steps](https://docs.brew.sh/Formula-Cookbook#adding-optional-steps) might be helpful for you:

> If you want to add an [`option`](https://rubydoc.brew.sh/Formula#option-class_method):
>
> ```rb
> class Yourformula < Formula
>   ...
>   option "with-ham", "Description of the option"
>   option "without-spam", "Another description"
>
>   depends_on "foo" => :optional  # will automatically add a with-foo option
>   ...
> ```
>
> And then to define the effects the [`option`](https://rubydoc.brew.sh/Formula#option-class_method)s have:
>
> ```rb
> if build.with? "ham"
>   # note, no "with" in the option name (it is added by the build.with? method)
> end
>
> if build.without? "ham"
>   # works as you'd expect. True if `--without-ham` was given.
> end
> ```

Comment: This looks promising thank you. Just a bit worried if it will work since they are not allowed in homebrew-core CI.

Comment: As long as you don’t intend to submit the formula to [homebrew-core](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core), it should be fine to use. (I assumed you already have your own tap, but if not, see [How to Create and Maintain a Tap](https://docs.brew.sh/How-to-Create-and-Maintain-a-Tap))

Comment: My intention was to do so, so yeah, I guess this is dead-end. Thank you anyway.